# Add 7 days to the existing date starting from a condition in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame in this format:

```
df1:
Date         Week    Visitors
2016-09-25   40      100
2016-10-02   41      200
.
.
2016-12-25   52      600
2017-01-08   01      500
2017-01-15   02      1000
2017-01-22   03      2000
.
.
```

I would like to subtract 7 days starting from Date when Week ==1 and Day(2017-01-08) >=7 for the rest of the data.

My Data Frame would be:

```
df1:
Date         Week    Visitors
2016-09-25   40      100
2016-10-02   41      200
.
.
2016-12-25   01      600
2017-01-01   01      500
2017-01-08   02      1000
2017-01-15   03      2000
.
.
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `df1 %>% mutate(Date = if_else(Week >= 1 | lubridate::day(Date) >= 7, Date - 7, Date))`

Comment: @alistaire, that would only change 2017-01-08 to 2017-01-01. I would like to decrement each date after that date by 7. 2017-01-15 should be changed to 2017-01-08 and so on until the last row of the data frame

Comment: It does. I'm not sure if you want `&` or `|`, but the conditional is true if the week is greater or equal to 1 or day is greater or equal to 7. Unless you mean the date is supposed to be later than 2017-01-08, in which case you need `Date >= as.Date('2017-01-08')`

Comment: I want every Date after 2017-01-01 to be reduced by 7. One row of my data frame is missing(2017-01-01) so I want to reduce each day by 7 starting 2017-01-08 till end of data frame

Comment: `df1 %>% mutate(Date = if_else(Date >= as.Date('2017-01-01'), Date - 7, Date))`? Your condition is still unclear.

Comment: Is the `Week>=1` condition necessary? Doesn't `Date>as.Date("2017-01-01")` do everything you need here?

Comment: @alistaire My first week for a new year should start before 2017-01-07 if it doesn't then I have to reduce each Date beyond 2017-01-07 in that data frame by 7.

Comment: I think both @alistaire and I have interpreted your question in a similar way, and both came up with similar solutions. I think I understand what you need a little better now, so I've edited my answer with a completely different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking turns out to be significantly different to what I thought, so I've edited my answer. I think what you're after is a check for each year, such that if "Week == 1" for that year is before Jan-07, then assume the first week is "missing", and act on that by moving all dates backward by 7 days. Here's how that could be achieved.

First, we'll make a column to specify just the year:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df1 )
df1[ , Year := format( Date, "%Y" )
     ]
```

Then, we'll define a function to check for the missing first week, and move the dates if appropriate:

```
checkAndMove <- function( d, w ) {
    month.day <- as.integer( format( d, "%m%d" ) )
    if( month.day[ w == 1 ] > 0106 ) {
        d <- d - 7
    }
    return( d )
}
```

Then, we can either apply this function to a single year of your choice:

```
df1[ Year == 2017, Date := checkAndMove( d = Date, w = Week ) ]
```

Or, we can let R run the check for all years at once, applying the change only when the function deems it appropriate:

```
df1[ , Date := checkAndMove( d = Date, w = Week ), by = Year ]
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this code, since I don't have much data to work with. If you can provide a little more data, I'm happy to run a test to make sure it behaves as expected.

Comment: My first Week of a new year might start anywhere between 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-06, but if the first week starts after 2017-01-06 then I have a missing first week